# How to plot best fit line for values in a list less than an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, filter, conditional-statements

I'm trying to plot a best fit line for when values in my list x are less than x_c (in this case 20).

```
plt.scatter(x,tf)
x_c = (20)
filter1 = [a < x_c for a in x]
m, b = np.polyfit(x[filter1], tr[filter1], 1)
plt.plot(x[filter1], m*x[filter1]+ b)
```

When I do that I get this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I also tried it with

```
filter = [x < x_c]
```

and that also did not work

Answer (score 0):

Python lists do not support boolean indexing. (But numpy arrays do!) You must select the items from your list that match your condition, and then use the new list for plotting:

```
good_x = [a for a in x if a < x_c]
....
plt.plot(good_x, ...)
```